# ASP.Net: Transparent background png image issue while trying to set an image as Background of td

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

I am trying to set an image as background in td.Its working fine with all browsers except IE6. I did google as this is famous png issue with IE6. I tried some solution using javascript but its working fine when i used img. In case of background i am not able to call any javascript method to solve the issue.

Help me if you have some solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that any solution exist for this problem. However, I wouldn't worry too much as IE6 market share is decreasing rapidly and in some geographies such as US/Europe, its less than 2-3%. See http://www.ie6countdown.com/

Said that IE6 support is must then I will suggest that you create an alternate image type (gif or jpeg) and use that instead of png. You can use IE6 specific CSS hacks to use the alternate version and thereby delivering the PNG to other browsers.

**EDIT**

Doesn't CSS such as below work for you

```
td.myClass {
  background-image: url(bg.png);
  _background-image: url(bg.gif); /* IE6 Hack */
}
```

Comment: Yeah it seems like but i can not use CSS hack for the same. I have tried some but they didn't work. My scenario is                        <td> background = "image path"</td> for this i need to know how this can be achieved for IE6

Comment: @VinaC - I solved this issue using javascript and applied to all png on a page.. i will update script here that would help to others and Thanks VinayC to reply.....